# Verb corresponding to schedule, but for a place (instead of time)

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

The verb "schedule" is used to denote a time (e.g."the meeting is scheduled for 8 am"). Is there a corresponding verb that denotes a place?

Comment: I'm wondering if *scheduled* wouldn't be OK for your use as well.  "We've scheduled the meeting for the large conference room" gets your point across pretty well.

Comment: I agree with @Brendon: *scheduling* as an activity entails more than just figuring out *when*; you also have to find a *where*, and possibly also a *why* and *what* (i.e. agenda), though I guess those latter two are more likely to be precursors to the *scheduling* activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A verb equivalent for *schedule* relating to place is *site*:

*We have sited the morning reception in the Mangosteen Room.*

*Site the portable flux capacitors for maximum exposure to the antimatter stream.*

> **site**, *tr.v.* 1 : to provide with a site; 2 : to put in position so as
>   to be able to perform a specific mission [Merriam-Webster]

Answer (score 2):

The verb *[situate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/situate)*, "To place on or into a physical location", may be used.  Alternatives include *locate, fix a place,* and *set a venue.*  (*[Venue](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/venue)* is a noun meaning "A place, especially the one where a given event is to happen".)

*Edit* As I note in a comment, one is more likely to hear sentences like the following

> The meeting is in the conference room.
>   The meeting will be held in the conference room.

rather than "The meeting is situated in the conference room".  If the meeting venue is under discussion, quite plausibly one might hear "We haven't decided where to situate the meeting", but again "We haven't decided where to hold the meeting" is more likely.

In facilities planning *vs.* meeting planning, cases using *situate* are a little more likely:  "We haven't scheduled this plant because we haven't situated it yet."

Comment: Regarding my specific example, I don't think that "the meeting is situated in the conference room" or would make sense. Do you?

Comment: @Quinn  Certainly it makes sense; but few would say it.  "The meeting is set in..." or "The meeting will be held in..." are more likely to be heard.  I think neither construction parallels "schedule" quite as well as does "situate", and your question asks for a "corresponding verb".

Comment: Quite right. The answer to OP's question is *"situate"*, with the caveat that in practice we simply don't normally use it anyway. To be honest, I'd rather say *"The meeting is scheduled for the conference room"* than *"...situated in..."* - even in a context where the actual date/time hadn't yet been set.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments, "schedule" works for locations too.  But if you're looking for a location-specific word, try [book (def. 27)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/book):

> to reserve (a place, passage, etc) or engage the services of (a performer, driver, etc) in advance: to book a flight; to book a band